# How can I save cookies in internal storage and reuse them?

Tags: android, cookies, webview, internal-storage

I've created an Android App with Web View that displays a web-site. Users have to login and my cookies lasts for 8 hours. I need to store the cookies into internal storage and then use that stored data to load the cookies again every time I start the app. Can someone help me ? I've checked lots of questions but I can't figure this out, I really need a code example for that. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CookieStore object represents a storage for cookie. Can store and retrieve cookies.

[CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html) will call `CookieStore.add` to save cookies for every incoming HTTP response, and call `CookieStore.get` to retrieve cookie for every outgoing HTTP request. A CookieStore is responsible for removing HttpCookie instances which have expired.

further information Click Hear: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieStore.html